# Yield Return Many?

Tags: c#

I find myself foreach-ing over IEnumerables a lot just so that I can return each result. Is there a way to compress something like this

```
foreach (var subSelector in subSelectors)
{
    foreach (var node in FindSingle(context, subSelector))
        yield return node;
}
```

To remove the inner foreach?

Comment: this has been asked many times and should be merged. search for "yield multiple enumerable"

Comment: @mafutrct: *No results found for "yield multiple enumerable".* Can you give an example?

Comment: This is what I found (granted, with a different search phrase): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055927/ienumerable-and-recursion-using-yield-return, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824934/rewrite-this-foreach-yield-to-a-linq-yield, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270024/nested-yield-return-with-ienumerable. However, I did not find the question I was looking for that explained exactly what was asked for. I also recall having asked this myself some time ago... I'll try and look it up in my Q list.

Comment: It was probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043050/c-performance-of-nested-yield-in-a-tree, which is not really related to this question. (I get the feeling I'm acting like a Wikipedian (even a German one). Sorry about that)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, there isn't, unless you completely replace every `yield return` with a single `return` statement using LINQ.

For example:

```
return someSet
    .Concat(someOtherSet.SelectMany(s => FindSingle(context, s));
```

Comment: Even though, it is not exactly the same, because "return" exits from the function immediately, while "yield return" does not

Answer (score 82):

This is a somewhat frequently requested feature that C# does not support. See this Connect item for details:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/256934/yield-return-to-also-yield-collections

The proposed syntax is usually something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> PreorderTraversal<T>(this BinaryTree<T> root)
{
    if (root == null) yield break;
    yield return root.Item;
    yield foreach root.Left.PreorderTraversal();
    yield foreach root.Right.PreorderTraversal();
}
```

If you are interested in playing with a C#-like language that supports this feature, take a look at Cω:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/comega/

You might also want to read this paper on the feature by the implementors of Cω:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/iterators.pdf

If you're interested in a non-C#-like language that supports this feature, take a look at the "yield!" feature of F#. (I just love that the name of the feature is "yield!")

Even if you are not interested in the theoretical stuff, it sounds like you face this situation as a practical problem. You should also read Wes Dyer's article on techniques for efficiently doing this sort of nested iteration without "yield foreach":

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/03/23/all-about-iterators.aspx

Comment: I thought Comega is already integrated into C#, so they stopped developing it. Is it still continuing to bring new ideas for future C# versions?

Comment: @Joan: Some of the ideas from C-omega have been integrated in C#, some of them have not. Whether any research or development continues on it, I do not know.

Comment: I think just `yield each` would sound better. Thanks for the answer! This is interesting.

Comment: Or "YieldMany", which would fit well with SelectMany

Comment: @mpen You may currently use `yield` as a class name, and `each` as a variable name, so there could be code containing the words `yield each` already. Now c# can determine that `yield` in `yield return` is a keyword because it is followed by another keyword; so in a similar vein `yield foreach` might be better.

Comment: @StrategyThinker: indeed, that is the standard proposed syntax; see Kiril's article from 2007: http://kirillosenkov.blogspot.com/2007/10/yield-foreach.html

Comment: Wes Dyer's article "All About Iterators" has been moved to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wesdyer/all-about-iterators

Comment: @StrategyThinker, but in `yield each x` will be one more word. If `yield` is a class and one of `each` or `x` is a variable, what is the other one? I don't remember any nonkeyword constructions from 3 or more words.

Comment: Do we need a keyword at all, or could C# infer this based on types? That is, in cases where the method returns IEnumerable(T) we would expect to yield on a T. But if we instead yield an IEnumerable(T) could that be enough to trigger a "yield foreach" without actually needing the "foreach" keyword? I suspect that answer is, "no", because a type might at the same time be both a T and an IEnumerable(T), but I don't want to dismiss this w/0 investigating how it might work. IE, we could always yield the plain T here; if someone wants IEnumerable(T) they could still manually loop through the items.

Comment: [continued] ... The caveat to that idea is it leaves the programmer open to bugs where they forget to, say, mention a specific property of an item, and instead of a compile-time error get code that does something they don't expect.

Answer (score 14):

With C# 7.0, local functions are allowed, which enables us to have a fairly neat approach

```
IEnumerable<T> FlatEnumerable(){
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> NestedEnumerable(){
       yield return myEnumerable1;
       yield return myEnumerable2;
    }

    return NestedEnumerable().SelectMany(e => e);
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions

Comment: I wonder about the downvote reasons.. This is short and maintainable.

Comment: I think this is really clean. Good suggestion!

Comment: I combined it with a Flatten extension for a bit more clean reading.                 
              public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source) => source.SelectMany(x => x);

Comment: hm - could someone add a sample on how this is used i dont fully graps whats happening here.

Comment: The local function is completely unnecessary in this case when you could just simply create an array of those enumerables instead.

Comment: an array wouldn't be exactly the same because you're losing the deferred execution that was presumably the MO in the first place.

Comment: This is only helpful if you only have one NestedEnumerable to return and nothing else.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx):

```
return subSelectors.SelectMany(subselector => FindSingle(context, subSelector));
```

This only works if you don't have any other yield return statements in your method.

Comment: Yeah... but then you can't yield anything more after that point.

Answer (score 2):

You can break your method into two. Given these extension methods:

```
public static class MultiEnumerableExtensions {
  public static IEnumerable<T> Pack<T>(this T item) {
    yield return item;
  }
  public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(
    this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> multiList) {
    return multiList.SelectMany(x => x);
  }
}
```

And using Eric Lippert's [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851997/yield-return-many/3856647#3856647), it becomes this:

```
public static class BinaryTreeExtensions {
  public static IEnumerable<T> PreorderTraversal<T>(this BinaryTree<T> root) {
    return PreorderTraversalMulti(root).Flatten();
  }
  private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> PreorderTraversalMulti<T>(
    this BinaryTree<T> root) {
    if (root == null) yield break;
    yield return root.Item.Pack(); // this packs an item into an enumerable
    yield return root.Left.PreorderTraversal();
    yield return root.Right.PreorderTraversal();
  }
}
```

The inner method yields enumerables of T instead of Ts, and the outer method just needs to flatten this result.

Comment: Looks like a lot of overhead for a small amount of syntactic sugar. I appreciate the suggestion though, it *is* interesting.

Comment: There's probably a threshold where it'd make sense to use it. Probably if you have more than a few "foreach yields" in your method. I think that Eric's example _barely_ qualifies. Other people might think otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of Linq!

```
return subSelectors.SelectMany(s => FindSingle(context, s));
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining @Jordao's answer and the fact that C#7 contains local functions, as @Oskar mentiond I think the following would be the "updated" answer:

```
        public static IEnumerable<T> PreorderTraversal<T>(this BinaryTree<T> root)
        {
            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> PreorderTraversalMulti<T>(
          this BinaryTree<T> root)
            {
                if (root == null) yield break;
                yield return root.Item.Pack(); // this packs an item into an enumerable
                yield return root.Left.PreorderTraversal();
                yield return root.Right.PreorderTraversal();
            }
            return PreorderTraversalMulti.Concat( PreorderTraversalMulti(root).Flatten());
        }
```

I used this for a different reason - to get all files up to 3 stages inside and finalized with this function:

```
public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> EnumerateFiles(DirectoryInfo sourceFolder, string pattern, int steps2Enter, int currStep = 0, int maximumNumFiles = 800)
    {
        int total = 0;
        IEnumerable<FileInfo> NestedFunc()
        {
            if (currStep > steps2Enter) yield break;
            if (sourceFolder == null) yield break;
            foreach (var file in sourceFolder.GetFiles(pattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                if (total++ > maximumNumFiles) yield break;
                yield return file;
            }
        }
        return NestedFunc().Concat(sourceFolder.EnumerateDirectories().SelectMany(s => EnumerateFiles(s, pattern, steps2Enter, currStep + 1, maximumNumFiles)));
    }
```

So yes - I'm still waiting for some syntatic sugar which will enable writing

```
yield return foreach...
```