# More compact way for "yield return"?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style, ienumerable, yield-return

I have this method that yields the values yielded by 2 methods:

```
private IEnumerable<Node> ParseEmptyElement()
{
    foreach (var node in ParseMembersOfObject()) 
    {
        yield return node;
    }

    foreach (var node in ParseNestedProperty()) 
    {
        yield return node;
    }
}
```

It seems **very verbose** for me.

Is there a better way express "yield all values from MethodX" and after that, do the same for MethodY?

Example:

```
private IEnumerable<Node> ParseEmptyElement()
{
    #yield all# items from ParseMembersOfObject();    
    #yield all# items from ParseNestedProperty();
}
```

I don't want to be force to write the *foreach loops* into a single line! but I also don't want to write fully-fledged *foreach loops* with curly braces and all the stuff :)

Comment: `return ParseMembersOfObject().Concat(ParseNestedProperty())` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: return yield range/collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415902/c-return-yield-range-collection)

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270024/nested-yield-return-with-ienumerable

Comment: @Marc won't that force evaluation & in-memory copying of the IEnumerable method results?.

Comment: @jklemmack nope, Concat does not evaluate.

Comment: Do you even want yield return? It is not simply a tense way to return a collection. Parse sounds like there are exceptions involved and lazy evaluation could bite you

Comment: @jklemmack What do you mean by force evalution? You mean eager evaluation of both collections? If so then no, `Concat` uses deferred execution.

Comment: Here's an [msdn reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894.aspx) that confirms it's deferred execution.

Comment: Oh awesome. Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Marc commented, this is equivalent:

```
private IEnumerable<Node> ParseEmptyElement()
{
    return ParseMembersOfObject().Concat(ParseNestedProperty());
}
```

[`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894.aspx) is implemented using deferred execution, so this will not evaluate your enumerables early.

Incidentally, `Concat` is [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,b4c65ba55f649b0e) with the `foreach` loops on a single line:

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> ConcatIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, 
                                                    IEnumerable<TSource> second) {
    foreach (TSource element in first) yield return element;
    foreach (TSource element in second) yield return element;
}
```

If you don't like Concat, and you still want braces, you could still keep them and just format your code more concisely:

```
private IEnumerable<Node> ParseEmptyElement()
{
    foreach (var node in ParseMembersOfObject()) { yield return node; }
    foreach (var node in ParseNestedProperty())  { yield return node; }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Concat doesn't help so much when you have code in-between. Please, take a look to this method: https://github.com/SuperJMN/OmniXAML/blob/master/Source/OmniXaml/Parsers/ProtoParser/XamlProtoInstructionParser.cs#L47